# Nice Easy jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a nice easy problem for you here.

This is a nice easy navigation script that uses the jQuery .load().

Problem is one of these pages uses the Google Maps API...

I found some code from a post on this forum that basically allowed you to load a map on demand.

I figure if I trigger loadmap() and loadscript() when a link is clicked this would work.

Problem being I haven't uses jQuery in a while and have completely forgot how to daisy chain functions...

So basically: I want the function to do the .load function but then call both LoadMap() and loadScript()....

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Overcomming Crome 
    </title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.jNav').click(function(){
            $('#sandbox').load($(this).attr('href'));
            return false;
          });
        });

        function loadMap() {
          map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
          map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 6);
          map.addOverlay(new GMarker(map.getCenter()));
        }

        function loadScript() {
          var script = document.createElement("script");
          script.type = "text/javascript";
          script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAA-O3c-Om9OcvXMOJXreXHAxQGj0PqsCtxKvarsoS-iqLdqZSKfxS27kJqGZajBjvuzOBLizi931BUow&async=2&callback=loadMap";
          document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Overcomming Crome
    </h1>
    <li><a href="page1.html" class="jNav">Load Page 1 to Sandbox</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html" class="jNav">Load Page 2 to Sandbox</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html" class="jNav">Load Page 3 to Sandbox</a></li>
    <div id="sandbox"></div>
</body>
```

Then this is my edited code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Overcomming Crome 
        </title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.jNav').click(function(){
                $('#sandbox').load($(this).attr('href'),function() {
                  loadMap();
                  loadScript();
                });
                return false;
              });
            });

            function loadMap() {
                alert("Function 1 loaded");
                map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
                map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 6);
                map.addOverlay(new GMarker(map.getCenter()));
            }

            function loadScript() {
                alert("Function 2 loaded");
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.type = "text/javascript";
                script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAA-O3c-Om9OcvXMOJXreXHAxQGj0PqsCtxKvarsoS-iqLdqZSKfxS27kJqGZajBjvuzOBLizi931BUow&async=2&callback=loadMap";
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Overcomming Crome
        </h1>
        <li><a href="page1.html" class="jNav">Load Page 1 to Sandbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html" class="jNav">Load Page 2 to Sandbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html" class="jNav">Load Page 3 to Sandbox</a></li>
        <div id="sandbox"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please note: "map" is on page1.html.... Can you see what I am trying to do?

Comment: you should try the new google maps api v3 :) just a thought

Comment: Its a great version - but it seemed to have a great deal more code - thus when I found this example for an earlier version I thought if I got this working then I could always upgrade

Comment: new version doesn't need an API key and it also has an easier api imho :)

Comment: if you don't know the answer to a problem then how do you know that it's 'easy'? just sayin'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you pass `&async=2` and `&callback=loadMap` to the Google maps API, it will automatically call the callback function (i.e. loadMap) once loaded.

```
$('#sandbox').load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
    loadScript();
    // loadMap(); <-- unnecessary; and might throw JavaScript error
});
```

Comment: This is true in the sense that it will say "Function 2 loaded" - "Function 1 Loaded" - "API Key Incorrect" - "Function 1 loaded". But if I remove the load Map function complete it fails to work

Comment: Sorry I was being an idiot - yes I see and have removed it. You have got to get top answer simply for reading more into the question.

Comment: hmm didn't get to read what function 2 does haha +1 for you sir

Answer (score 1):

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
```

you don't have any element by the id map

also the load function has a callback so you can do:

```
$('#sandbox').load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
  loadMap();
  loadScript();
});
```

Comment: Hello, Right so the problem being the map element is present on page1.html. I have edited the code using your example - I have added alerts that let me know when the two functions load - so far I only get "Function 1 loaded" any reason why?

Comment: like i said, your google maps v2 must be complaining. you need an API for that right? if you have firebug, check your console and check if there's an error in loading your map

Answer (score 1):

You mean passing a callback function, like:

```
$('#sandbox').load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
  loadMap();
  loadScript();
});
```

This will call `loadMap()` and `loadScript()` when `load()` is completed.

Comment: They are loaded dynamically via `load` function.

Comment: @gor - How does you comment relate to posting the exact same answer as I did?

Answer (score 1):

The solution isn't to 'daisy chain' the functions, as that would still execute them in order. You need to wait until the external data is loaded before calling the other methods, by passing in a callback function to `load`:

```
$('#sandbox').load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
    loadScript();
    loadMap();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `load` function should look like this:

```
$('#sandbox').load($(this).attr('href') function(){
    loadScript();
    loadMap();
});
```